# AWS SDK Go Service Operation Unsuccessful (Terraform)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Trying to create (Amazon MemoryDB for Redis) resources using Terraform. The problem is no available resources yet through Terraform however Terraform does make provisions using Cloud control.

Currently experiencing the following error:

```
Error: AWS SDK Go Service Operation Unsuccessful

Calling Cloud Control API service GetResource operation returned: 
operation error CloudControl: GetResource, https response  
error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: dd4b43be-f57c-48be-ab08- 
ea1da10dbf5c, InvalidRequestException: AWS::MemoryDB::SubnetGroup  
Handler returned status FAILED: The parameter SubnetGroupName is 
not a valid identifier. Identifiers must begin with a       
letter; must contain only ASCII letters, digits, and hyphens; and 
must not end with a hyphen or contain two consecutive      
hyphens. (Service: MemoryDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 
c704c59a-aea5-449a-9e08-dbc53b44650c, Extended Request ID: null)  
(HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest, RequestToken: 1d771c74-5a42- 
464c-b944-fac3ef553ea9)
```

Here is the code for the resource:

```
resource "awscc_memorydb_subnet_group" "example1632-groupname" {
subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.enrichment-subnet-1.id,aws_subnet.enrichment-subnet-2.id]
subnet_group_name = "example1632-groupname"}
```

Don't find anything wrong with the subnet group name so not sure what's wrong?
Please help.

Comment: Please don't post errors as screenshots, but instead add them as properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: Exactly the same issue related to Redis now. Updated version but nothing change.

Comment: Have you tried with any other name? could it be the `-` in the name?